# Find spring constant of frame structure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, statistics

I would like to calculate the spring constant of a frame structure.
I thought that I could do it like this:

1. I apply a point force on the structure:
   [image]
2. Then I calculate the displacement at that same point:
   [image]

Finnaly, I asume that the material bends within its elastic limit:
$k=\frac{F}{\delta_y}$

**Question1: Do you agree with this method ?**

**Question2: If I have a different type of loading, for instance a distributed load, would the spring constant change ?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would change.

For example same load if applied at quarter span would cause less deflection and a different curve.

Hence bigger K.

basically for the type of loading you display applying the load at center corrolates to smallest K.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I apply a continous loading (pressure) how can I find the spring index? Do you know?

Comment: For continius loading say same load as previous one : P if spread over all or part if span, will cause less deflection so the K would be bigger.

Comment: I see. How do you calculate k ? Do you use the equivalent force at applied to the centroid of the continius  loading ?

Comment: I would use something like Hardy- Cross method to quickly calculate the frames stresses and deflctiins.